# Matrix projection onto positive semidefinite cone with respect to the spectral norm

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, least-squares, positive-semidefinite, projection

On page 399 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook), it is stated that the projection of a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix $X_0$ onto the set of symmetric $n \times n$ positive semidefinite matrices $S^n_+$ is found in the following way:

- Find the spectral (eigenvalue) decomposition $$X_0 = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i v_i^T$$
- Define the projection $$X = \sum_{i=1}^n \max\{\lambda_i, 0\} v_i v_i^T$$

It is proven in the book that $X$ is the solution of the problem

$$\underset{X}{\text{minimize}} \quad \| X - X_0 \|_F^2 \quad \text{subject to} \quad X \succeq 0$$

where $\|A\|_F^2 = \operatorname{tr} \left(A^T A\right)$ is a square of the Frobenius norm. In other words, $X$ is the projection of $X_0$ onto symmetric positive semidefinite matrix cone with respect to the Frobenius norm.

I have also found a proof of this in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436094/find-the-matrix-projection-on-the-set-of-symmetric-positive-semi-definite-matrix).

Now the book also states (without a proof, or at least it is not obvious for me from the material) that $X$ is also a solution to the problem

$$\underset{X}{\text{minimize}} \quad \| X - X_0 \|_2 \quad \text{subject to} \quad X \succeq 0$$

where $\|A\|_2$ ($A$ being symmetric) is the spectral norm,

$$\|A\|_2 = \max_{i=1, \dots, n}|\lambda_i| = \max\{\lambda_1, -\lambda_n\}$$

where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \dots \geq \lambda_n$. How to prove this?

Comment: Hint: you can make the problem easier by first showing that the result is true for diagonal matrices and then showing that the general problem can be reduced to one involving a diagonal matrix $X_{0}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X_0 = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i v_i^T$ be the eigenvalue decomposition of matrix $X_0$ with $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \dots \geq \lambda_n$. Assume $\lambda_n < 0$, as otherwise the projection of $X_0$ onto positive semidefinite cone would be itself. Then we have
\begin{equation}
v_i^T X_0 v_i = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_i v_i^T v_j v_j^T v_i = \lambda_i
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
||X_0||_2 = \max\{\lambda_1, -\lambda_n\} = \max\{v_1^T X_0 v_1, -v_n^T X_0 v_n\} = \max\{\sup_{||v||_2=1} v^T X_0 v, -\inf_{||v||_2=1} v^T X_0 v\}
\end{equation}
Now let $X$ be any symmetric positive semidefinite matrix. We have
\begin{equation}
||X - X_0||_2 \geq \sup_{||v||_2 = 1} v^T (X - X_0) v \geq v_n^T (X - X_0) v_n = v_n^T X v_n - v_n^TX_0v_n \geq -\lambda_n
\end{equation}
Now if we define $X = \sum_{i=1}^n \max\{\lambda_i, 0\} v_i v_i^T$, we have $||X - X_0||_2 = -\lambda_n$. Therefore, the defined matrix is the projection of $X_0$ onto positive semidefinite cone.